# flex блок не выравнивается по центру

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

flex блок `<nav>` не выравнивается по центру. Никак не пойму почему. Верхний ведь выровнялся. Как его правильно выровнять?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoBold:700&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoMedium:500&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoRegular&subset=cyrillic');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e5799;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}

header .Logo_and_title {
  height: 200px;
  color: #323246;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .Logo_and_title .logo img {
  padding: 45px;
}

header .Logo_and_title h1 {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .Logo_and_title h2 {
  font-family: 'RobotoMedium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

header .resort {
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #212121;
  text-align: center;
}

header nav {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

header nav .item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

header .awards {
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="Logo_and_title">
      <div class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"> </div>
      <div class="titles">
        <h1>Skadi FLS leaderbord</h1>
        <h2>Global list of best skiers in Skadi FLSski resorts</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resort">Schladming: Galsterberg, Hauser Kaibling, Dachstain, Gletscher, Reiteralm, Fageralm, Hoc...</div>
    <nav>
      <div class="item">Today</div>
      <div class="item">The week</div>
      <div class="item">Season</div>
    </nav>
    <div class="awards">
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="selected_list">
      <div class="num">1</div>
      <div class="name">Ivan</div>
      <div class="dist">172.1km</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: `width: 100%` или `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 2):

Получилось так

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoBold:700&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoMedium:500&subset=cyrillic');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoRegular&subset=cyrillic');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e5799;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 0%, #ffffff 38%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);
}

header .Logo_and_title {
  height: 200px;
  color: #323246;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header .Logo_and_title .logo img {
  padding: 45px;
}

header .Logo_and_title h1 {
  font-family: 'RobotoBold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

header .Logo_and_title h2 {
  font-family: 'RobotoMedium', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}

header .resort {
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #212121;
  text-align: center;
}

header .topmenu {
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

header nav {
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header nav .item {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  font-family: 'RobotoRegular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

header .awards {
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="Logo_and_title">
      <div class="logo"> <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"> </div>
      <div class="titles">
        <h1>Skadi FLS leaderbord</h1>
        <h2>Global list of best skiers in Skadi FLSski resorts</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="resort">Schladming: Galsterberg, Hauser Kaibling, Dachstain, Gletscher, Reiteralm, Fageralm, Hoc...</div>
    <div class="topmenu">
      <nav>
        <div class="item">Today</div>
        <div class="item">The week</div>
        <div class="item">Season</div>
      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="awards">
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="selected_list">
      <div class="num">1</div>
      <div class="name">Ivan</div>
      <div class="dist">172.1km</div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Верхние блоки не выровнены,они просто на всю ширину страницы.